# Loop getting cin input

Tags: c++, multithreading

Is it possible to create a while loop like:

```
bool stop_input = false;

while (!stop_input) {
    // Keep getting inputed string
    // Maybe like std::getline(std::cin, str_input);
}
```

Where this would keep looping and getting what the user inputted into console without stopping (freezing) like when doing`std::cin` or `std::getline()`.

I am interested in this to have a seperate thread which would do other stuff while waiting for user to input something and press enter then `stop_input` would go true and the user input would get disabled.

Is this possible? How?

EDIT:

For example If I did:

```
void test()
{
    std::string str;
    while (!stop_input) {
        std::getline(std::cin, str);
    }
}
```

If I created a function like above, compiled it and started a debugger, the debugger (program) would stop when std::getline() would get called the second time. I dont want this to happen, I want this loop to run continiously untill stopped by setting `stop_input = true;`

EDIT2:

Main thread:

```
void someFunction()
{
    string read_input;
    thread get_input = thread(readInput, &read_input);

    while(1) {
        if (buttonPressed(ENTER) {
            stop_input = true;
            get_input.join();

            // Do something with 'read_input' string.
        } else if (buttonPressed(ESC) {
           stop_input = true;
           get_input.join()

           // Discard 'read_input' string and return from this function.
           break;
        }
    }
}
```

Reading thread:

```
void readInput(string* input)
{
    while (!stop_input) {
        //Get input
    }
}
```

P.S. Ofcourse main thread would be doing some work behind also, not related to input reading.

Comment: Your solution involves Operating System specific features, like being notified when a *key* is *pressed* or polling to see when a *key status* has changed.  Since you didn't indicate your OS in you post, can't help you further.  Search the internet for "stackoverflow c++ keypress".

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I am able to get a keypress. My question was wether it is possible to implement input reading like described?

Comment: Do you want your program *interrupted* when a key is pressed, or released?  Do you want your program to *poll* the status of the keyboard?  Different methods for processing input.  I recommend placing the Input processing into a separate thread.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I have a felling you're not understanding my question (its probably badly worded). Forget about the keypress, that is done. Now, std::cin or std::getling() when called they freeze the program, preventing other code to continue executing. What I want to do is, have a seperate thread in which something like std::cin or std::getline() would run but without stopping (freezing), it would continiously run and get user input untill some bool gets set. I hope I made it clear now (I am not a native english speaker).

Comment: I'm not sure if the term "GUI thread" applies to a console, but I don't think user input should come from anywhere but the main thread. Having a main thread and a worker thread, what's the reason you need the main thread performing your task?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Please look at edit.

Comment: Your question is still not 100% clear to me. Maybe you can try to describe a possible use-case.

Comment: @DrPepperJo Please see edit, I've had something like this in mind.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I've added an use-case, maybe this will clear it up a bit.

Comment: I still don't understand where your input is supposed to come from. And the use-case looks pretty synchronous to me, just wrap the read loop around the rest of the program.

Comment: @DrPepperJo Main thread would be doing other work unrelated to input reading. Thats why I need both input reading and other work to be going on at the same time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130895/discussion-between-drpepperjo-and-user1806687).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I got your question right, but if you just want to run something in a thread and permit input until the task in the thread has finished, this is how I would do it:

```
std::vector< int > v;
std::atomic< bool > stop_input( false );
std::thread t( [ &v, &stop_input ]() 
{
  for( int i = 0; 1'000'000'000 > i; ++i ) v.push_back( i );
  stop_input = true;
} );
std::string m;
while( !stop_input )
{
  std::cin >> m;
  std::cout << "Your message: " << m << std::endl;
}
t.join();
```

However, this will only terminate after a user input following the termination of the task in the thread. It will not "interrupt" the `std::cin`.

Comment: No, exactly the opposite, please look at my recent comment.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you'd have two threads, one waiting for user input to then wake up the other thread?

You create a thread that'll take care of the loop, then your other thread takes user input and sets the bool. The looping thread continually calls the other thread to see if there was user input..

Like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

using namespace std;

string s;
bool b = false;

void doStuff()
{
    int i = 0;
    while (!b)
    {
        cout << i << ' ';
        ++i;
        this_thread::yield();
        //this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(1));
    }
    cout << "you wrote: " << s << endl;
}

int main()
{
    thread t(doStuff);
    char c;
    while ((c = cin.get()) != '\n')
        s += c;
    b = true;
    t.join();
}
```

Sleep and yield automatically blocks the thread and calls another available one. get() automatically blocks its thread too. If you want non-blocking stuff, then that's probably OS dependent...

EDIT:

You can detach the thread so it executes independently, then put a lock around shared resources before accessing them.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>

using namespace std;

mutex m;
string s;
bool stopInput = false;

char c = 0;

void readInput()
{
    while (!stopInput)
    {
        m.lock();
        c = cin.get();
        s += c;
        m.unlock();
    }
}

int main()
{
    thread t(readInput);
    t.detach();

    while (true)
    {
        m.lock();
        if (isEnter(c))
        {
            stopInput = true;
            cout << "Input: " << s << endl;
            break;
        }
        else if (isEscape(c))
        {
            stopInput = true;
            break;
        }
        m.unlock();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem seems to be about thread synchronization.

Assuming stop_input itself is properly synchronized, e.g. by virtue of it being an atomic_bool, that will still not prevent your thread from doing its thing inside the while loop's body when stop_input is set to true immediately after the check.

What exactly is it that you want to achieve? Knowing that, we may be able to help you find a proper thread-safe and thread-aware solution to your specific problem :)

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to let `getline` (or `cin.get`, `cin.peek`, etc) run in a separate thread together with an "exit"-variable like "stop_input" (see example below).

Please note that setting `stop_input=true` will clearly not interrupt `getline` (or `cin.get`, `cin.peek`, ...) once it has been called. Note further, that in loop like `while (!stop_input) { std::getline(std::cin, str); ... }`, it is unlikely that the main thread has the chance to set `stop_input=true` before the loop is re-entered. So it is likely that the main thread cannot stop input immediately after a user has entered a value; `getline` will be entered once more, before the loop can react on any change of `stop_input`.

One should further take care that getline is not used by other threads as well, because - at least to my knowledge - it is not thread safe.

```c
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>

bool stop_input = false;
std::queue<std::string> commandQueue;
std::mutex commandQueueMutex;

void getLineUntilInputStopped()
{
    std::string str;
    while (!stop_input) {
        std::getline(std::cin, str);
        if (str == "stopinput")
            stop_input = true;

        commandQueueMutex.lock();
        commandQueue.push(str);
        commandQueueMutex.unlock();
    }
    std::cout << "Listening on input stopped.";
}


int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    std::thread t(getLineUntilInputStopped);
    t.detach();

    bool exit = false;
    while (!exit)
    {
        std::string command = "";
        commandQueueMutex.lock();
        if (commandQueue.size() > 0)
        {
            command = commandQueue.front();
            commandQueue.pop();
        }
        commandQueueMutex.unlock();

        if (command.size() > 0)
        {
            if (command == "exit")
            {
                exit = true;
                std::cout << "exit program.";
            }
            else
            {
                std::cout << "command '" << command << "' entered.";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "in the meanwhile do something else\n";
            std::this_thread::sleep_for (std::chrono::seconds(3));
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```